# Pagination next page should be 2 but is 0

Tags: php, mysql

The first page should be 1 but its -1 and the next page should be 2 but its 0.

How can I make this work? I have tried to edit the $page but when I do, the if/else get wierd.

**I added the whole code...**

```
 ...
$resultt= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE AND country='$okc' AND state='$oks'";

if(!empty($a1) && empty($a2)){
  $resultt .= " AND aar>=";
  ...
}
```

There are more than 1 if statement.

```
         $result = mysqli_query($con,"$resultt");
         $rec_limit = 19;
         $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
         $rec_count = $row[0];

         if( isset($_GET['page'] ) )
         {
            $page = $_GET['page'] + 1;
            $offset = $rec_limit * $page ;
         }
         else
         {
            $page = 0;
            $offset = 0;
         }
         $left_rec = $rec_count - ($page * $rec_limit);

         $resultt .= "LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";
         $sql = $resultt;

         $retval = mysqli_query( $con, "$resultt" );

         if( $page > 0 )
         {
            $last = $page - 1;
            echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\">Last 10 Records</a> |";
            echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$page\">Next 10 Records</a>";
         }

         else if( $page == 0 )
         {
            echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$page\">Next 10 Records</a>";
            }

         else if( $left_rec < $rec_limit )
         {
            $last = $page - 2;
            echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\">Last 10 Records</a>";
         }

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

}
```

Comment: If this is `php` you may want to change `$_GET{'page'}` to `$_GET['page']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change parts of code to get it to work. `$_GET['page']` should give you the queried page number itself, so don't try to manipulate it.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE country='$okc' AND state='$oks'"
$rec_limit = 10;
$result = mysqli_query( $con, $sql );
$row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result );
$rec_count = $row[0];
$left_rec = $rec_count - ( $rec_limit * $page );


$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? intval($_GET['page']) : 1;
$offset = $rec_limit * ( $page - 1 ) ;

$sql.= " LIMIT $rec_limit OFFSET $offset";
$result = mysqli_query( $con, $sql );

$row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result );

if( $page > 1 ){
    $last = $page - 1;
    echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\">Last 10 Records</a> |";
    echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$page\">Next 10 Records</a>";
}else if( $page == 1 ){
    echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$page\">Next 10 Records</a>";
}else if( $left_rec < $rec_limit ){
    $last = $page - 2;
    echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\">Last 10 Records</a>";
}

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ){

    // use $row to echo row contents ...

}
```

Comment: can you add an explanation here?

Comment: Sorry for that, I'll add some

Comment: The $next and $last get wrong when i do this and the $row doesnt seem to work as it should

Comment: Updated my answer. take a look. keep in mind that SOF is not somewhere people code for you. Here you may just get the idea and do it yourself

Answer (score 1):

$_GET is an array like your $row.

to access array keys you always use [].

change your get into $_GET['page']

even better:

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? intval($_GET['page']) : 1;
```

is page set then convert value to int, because you dont know whats incomming.
if not set take page 1.

btw. constructs like this:

```
$resultt = "LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";
```

can/will cause sql injections bugs within you homepage!
never build a sql with variables!
Use parameters instead!

Comment: Still gets the same problem when editing the code to that